# Авторизация и чтение - CURL

Tags: php

Доброго времени. Сделал авторизацию себе на сайте

```
function login($url,$login,$pass){

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  'cookiefile.txt'); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 

    $post="name_user=".$login."&password_user=".$pass."&submit_avtoriz=Войти&control_avtoriz=send_avtoriz";

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url.'');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    //echo $html;

   return $html;
}


login("http://sait.ru/registr/enter/","admin","123456");
```

проблем никаких, все авторизуется. Подскажите, как теперь сделать переход на главную страницу через CURL, чтобы авторизация сохранилась ?

Пробую потом вызвать

```
Read("http://sait.ru/");
```

сразу эту функцию, но не получается : страница открывается,а вот авторизация слетает

```
function Read($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url.'');
    $html = curl_exec($ch);

   echo $html; //покажем страницу
}
```

Comment: Естественно она слетает. Так как следующий запрос ничего не знает о предыдущем. Для этого и сделаны сессии и вот это всё.

Comment: понял ..Не обратил внимание ! Спасибо

Comment: Если решили проблему, добавьте ответ пожалуйста. Куки я вижу вы передавали и ранее при запросе главной. В чём тогда была проблема?